# Make Private Class Accessible from SDK But Not App

Tags: java, android, oop, sdk, access-modifiers

Say I have the following class in an SDK library:

```
public class Everything {
    public String external1;
    public String external2;
    public String internal1;
    public String internal2;
}
```

That I'm trying to split up into 2 separate classes:

```
public class External {
    public String external1;
    public String external2;
}

private class Internal extends External {
    public String internal1;
    public String internal2;
}
```

With the intention of exposing the `External` class to any app injecting my SDK, while hiding and not making the `Internal` class accessible to any application injecting said SDK. Is there a way to accomplish this without having to set my `Internal` class as private so that I may still have access to it and its members across my SDK library internally?

Effectively, `Internal` will become the new `Everything` class that will contain both `External` and `Internal` members. But only my SDK library should be aware of this larger class. Is there a better approach with interfaces/inheritance?? Nested private classes?? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you have a method that takes the external object, generates (or retrieves) the internal portion of it, and creates a new instance of `Everything`? There is no way that the application using the SDK is going to be able to give you an instance of `Internal` if it only knows that `External` exists (without them using some funky reflection logic which shouldn't be necessary). Having them in the same class is also a bad idea if this is sensitive information because they can always use reflection to get the value of fields, even if they're private.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.